# Need to add a subquery or something else to get a record from repeated rows?

Tags: sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID,COUNT(CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID )
FROM CONTRACT_QUOTE 
GROUP BY CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID 
HAVING COUNT(CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID) > 1
```

[image]

Which basically shows the ids and the amount of time repated. But on each id there's a field that is the "CONTRACT_QUOTE_NO", but I don't know how to show them.

[image]

I've tried to do a subquery, but failed hard at it. Here's the code :

```
SELECT c1.CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID, c1.CONTRACT_QUOTE_NO, COUNTING = (SELECT COUNT(c2.CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID)
                             FROM CONTRACT_QUOTE c2
                             WHERE c1.CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID = c2.CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID)
FROM CONTRACT_QUOTE c1
GROUP BY c1.CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID,c1.CONTRACT_QUOTE_NO
HAVING COUNTING > 1
```

What could i do?

Comment: So, in the first example you're grouping by CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID which are apparently repeated with unique CONTRACT_QUOTE_NO entries.  So, which Quote No do you want?  The last one?

Comment: Each CONTRACT_QUOTE_ID has a CONTRACT_QUOTE_NO, and there are IDs repeated, but have different contract quotes no. I would like to show the repeated amount of ids, and their contract_quote_no.

Comment: If you're using MS-SQL you could use CROSS APPLY and FOR XML PATH('') to create a comma delimited list of the repeat entries.  I'm not sure since your DBMS wasn't tagged.

Comment: No its a weird one called LIMS Labware, and uses the TOAD database.